# Scrappy response different than browser response

Tags: beautifulsoup, urllib2, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a this page with scrapy:

```
http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?dref=4815&sort=SA&startat=7391
```

and the response which I get is different than what I see in the browser. Browser response has the correct page, while scrapy response is:

```
http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?dref=4815&sort=SA&startat=1
```

page. I have tried with urllib2 but still have the same issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You mean, when you request the page via scrapy, it redirects you?

Comment: it might be that the site is using javascript.Scrapy by default doesnt. You should use a middleware or a downloadhandler.

Answer (score 4):

I don't really understand the issue, but usually a different response for a browser and scrapy is caused by one these:

- the server analyzes your `User-Agent` header, and returns a specially crafted page for mobile clients or bots;
- the server analyzes the cookies, and does something special when it looks like you are visiting for the first time;
- you are trying to make a POST request via scrapy like the browser does, but you forgot some form fields, or put wrong values
- etc.

There is no universal way to determine what's wrong, because it depends on the server logic, which you don't know. If you are lucky, you will analyze and fix all the mentioned issues and will make it work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am making a get request and and have set User-Agent in scrap to a browser Mozilla/5.0. However When i visit the page through a browser I get a referrer  "http://www.barnesandnoble.com/s?dref=4815&sort=SA&startat=7391" where as with scrapy the referrer is an empty string "". I am trying to set a referrer with scrapy but that has not worked yet.

Comment: Try using wireshark to see what's sent by Firefox and scrapy and analyze the differences.