# How to send JavaScript and Cookies Enabled in Scrapy?

Tags: python, screen-scraping, mechanize, scrapy

I am scraping a website using Scrapy which require cooking and java-script to be enabled. I don't think I will have to actually process javascript. All I need is to pretend as if javascript is enabled.

Here is what I have tried:
1) Enable Cookies through following in settings

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
```

2) Using download middleware for cookies

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.cookies.CookiesMiddleware':700
}
```

3) Sending 'X-JAVASCRIPT-ENABLED': 'True'

```
DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS={
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en',
    'X-JAVASCRIPT-ENABLED': 'True'
}
```

but none of them is working with me. Can you please suggest any idea or give me some direction ?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 6):

You should try [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) JS engine with [scrapyjs](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyjs). Here is a example of how to set it up in your spider project:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapyjs.SplashMiddleware': 725,
}
```

[Scraping hub](http://crawlera.com/) which is the same company behind Scrapy, has [special instances](http://scrapinghub.com/splash/) to run your spiders with splash enabled.

Then yield `SplashRequest` instead of `Request` in your spider like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = ["http://example.com", "http://example.com/foo"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                endpoint='render.html',
                args={'wait': 0.5},
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        # response.body is a result of render.html call; it
        # contains HTML processed by a browser.
        # …
```

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, there is no a universal solution. You have to debug the site, to see how it determines that Javascript is not supported/enabled by your client.

I don't think the server looks at `X-JAVASCRIPT-ENABLED` header. Maybe there is a cookie set by Javascript when the page loads in a real javascript enabled browser? Maybe the server looks at `user-agent` header?

See also [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834736/scrappy-response-different-than-browser-response/13835141#13835141).

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy doesn't support java script.

but

you can use some other library with Scrapy for executing JS , like Webkit, Selenium etc,

and you don't needs to enable cookies (`COOKIES_ENABLED = True`), not even required to add `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` in your `settings.py` because they are already available in [default scrapy settings](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/settings/default_settings.py)

Comment: Akhter, Thanks for the reply. As I said, I won't need to process JavaScript. The server won't give me actual page if it seeds javascript is not enabled on the requesting source. I just need to send a signal to the server that javascript and cookies are enabled.