# scraping ASPX website not working - Crawled 31 pages (at 31 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: python, asp.net, scrapy

I am trying to scrape an ASP website that contains [crime statistics in Israel](https://www.police.gov.il/mapskifout.aspx).
In the website, a user is supposed to choose a town from a drop-down list:
[image]

following this selection, the user's result is returned to the bottom of that same page:
[image]

For some reason, scrapy seems to be crawling the website, but not returning anything:

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.police.gov.il/mapskifout.aspx> (referer: https://www.police.gov.il/mapskifout.aspx)
[scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 31 pages (at 31 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

**Code:**

```
import scrapy
# from ..items import ViewstateItem
class SpidyQuotesViewStateSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'crimeStat'
    start_urls = ['https://www.police.gov.il/mapskifout.aspx']
    download_delay = 1.5

    def parse(self, response):
        for town in response.css('li.rcbItem::text').extract():
            yield scrapy.FormRequest(
                'https://www.police.gov.il/mapskifout.aspx',
                formdata={
                    'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceMain$contentPageMain$TownComboBox': town,
                    '__VIEWSTATE': response.css('input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').extract_first()
                },

                callback=self.parse_results
            )


    def parse_results(self, response):
        # items = ViewstateItem
        for data in response.css("div.resultset resultsetprint"):
            yield {
                'crimeType': data.xpath('//*[@id="statistics"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/text()').get(),
                'crimeAmount': data.xpath('//*[@id="statistics"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/text()').get(),
                'carAmount': data.xpath('//*[@id="statistics"]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/text()').get(),
            }
```

**Any tips would be appreciated and thanks in advance!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look for **where the data is coming from** by following requests it sends you will find out it is coming from something like this link: https://www.police.gov.il/MapSkifoutService?city=7900&street=&house=&subjects=1,2,10,11&quarter=1,2,3&year=2019
So by specifying year and **city code** you will get your desire data.
But how can you get city codes?
City codes are exist in script part of main page source so you can get it like this:

```py
import requests
import json
import re

base_url = 'https://www.police.gov.il/MapSkifoutService?' \
                   'city=%(city)s&street=&house=&subjects=1,2,10,11&quarter=1,2,3&year=%(year)s'
s = requests.Session()
res = s.post('https://www.police.gov.il/mapskifout.aspx')
codes = re.findall('itemData":(.*)],', res.content.decode('utf-8'))[0] + "]"
json_codes = json.loads(codes)

for town in json_codes:
    json_response = json.loads(s.post(base_url % {'city': town['value'], 'year': '2019'})
                               .content.decode('utf-8'))
    print(json_response['Stats'])
```

Sample output would be:

```
[{'Title': 'נתוני עבירות פליליות', 'GroupId': 1, 'Statistics': [{'Id': 1, 'Subject': 'גניבה מתוך רכב', 'CountFact': 2, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 2, 'Subject': 'גניבת רכב         ', 'CountFact': 10, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 10, 'Subject': 'התפרצות לדירות', 'CountFact': 2, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 11, 'Subject': 'התפרצות לבתי עסק ומוסדות', 'CountFact': 2, 'CountFact2': 0}], 'CountTikia': 16, 'SummaryTitle': 'סה"כ תיקי חקירה שנפתחו באזור הנבחר', 'sougTitle': 'סוג עבירה', 'countTitle': 'כמות עבירות', 'CountTikia2': 0}]
[{'Title': 'נתוני עבירות פליליות', 'GroupId': 1, 'Statistics': [{'Id': 1, 'Subject': 'גניבה מתוך רכב', 'CountFact': 4, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 2, 'Subject': 'גניבת רכב         ', 'CountFact': 10, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 10, 'Subject': 'התפרצות לדירות', 'CountFact': 16, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 11, 'Subject': 'התפרצות לבתי עסק ומוסדות', 'CountFact': 5, 'CountFact2': 0}], 'CountTikia': 35, 'SummaryTitle': 'סה"כ תיקי חקירה שנפתחו באזור הנבחר', 'sougTitle': 'סוג עבירה', 'countTitle': 'כמות עבירות', 'CountTikia2': 0}]
[{'Title': 'נתוני עבירות פליליות', 'GroupId': 1, 'Statistics': [{'Id': 1, 'Subject': 'גניבה מתוך רכב', 'CountFact': 9, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 2, 'Subject': 'גניבת רכב         ', 'CountFact': 12, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 10, 'Subject': 'התפרצות לדירות', 'CountFact': 17, 'CountFact2': 0}, {'Id': 11, 'Subject': 'התפרצות לבתי עסק ומוסדות', 'CountFact': 4, 'CountFact2': 0}], 'CountTikia': 40, 'SummaryTitle': 'סה"כ תיקי חקירה שנפתחו באזור הנבחר', 'sougTitle': 'סוג עבירה', 'countTitle': 'כמות עבירות', 'CountTikia2': 0}]
```

Comment: thanks you! I Changed the for loop to `for town in json_codes:` and changed formdata to `'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceMain$contentPageMain$TownComboBox': town.get("value")`, but still it doesn't seem to work. I that I am missing another something...

Comment: I got it, I made some updates, take a look at it. The problem is coming from Scrapy doesn't support JavaScript. You can do it with `requests` like I mentioned above or if you want it to be done with Scrapy try [scrapy-splash, SplashRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391677/how-to-send-javascript-and-cookies-enabled-in-scrapy)