# Scrapy unable to select class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrap a website but whenever i use class="something" i got empty list...

[website](http://www.bonnito.com/categories/RTS-Products-Women/cid-CU00065063.aspx?RSS=pgZZ2QQdivZZctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl02_ShowcaseQQsortZZPASCQQviewZZH)

```
hxs.select('//div[@class="bucket"]').extract()
```

Did i am doing something wrong

But this is working...

```
hxs.select("//div[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl00_ctl02_divMain']").extract()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find string `"bucket"` in the source of the mentioned web page. So there is no any element with this class, that's why you get an empty list.

Comment: Man than what is this ...<div class="bucketgroup"></div> Just try inspect element and then view source...

Comment: I did the same - no string `bucket` (or `bucketgroup`). But even if there was element `<div class="bucketgroup"></div>`, it would not be selected by xpath `'//div[@class="bucket"]'`

Comment: Actually inside bucketgroup their is bucket class....which i am trying to select...Here take a look...http://notepad.cc/xawuge15...

Comment: I think your scrapy spider gets a different version of the page, not the one you see in your browser. You can run a scrapy shell to confirm this. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834736/scrappy-response-different-than-browser-response/13835141#13835141